# Why does the electric potential of a conducting surface becomes zero when it is connected with another surface with potential zero?

Tags: electromagnetism

> Suppose there a conductor at potential $\theta$, enclosed by a surface of potential $0$. Why, when the conductor is connected to the zero-potential surface, its potential becomes zero as well?

1. Why the potential becomes zero?
2. What happens to the charge on the conductor?
3. What is the role of the wire in this system?

Comment: Where is your 0 level set? Is this an infinite size surface?

Comment: @Viktor No this surface is of finite size. It completely encloses the conductor so you may think of it as 'infinity' surface.(Well, shrink infinity boundary to the surface boundary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in the same order as you asked them:

1. The thing to remember is that for a conductor the charges move such that every point on the conductor is at the same potential. By connecting the conductor to the surface at potential $0$ this means both the conductor and the surface must now have the same potential. If the surface is **defined** to have a potential of $0$ then this means that the conductor must now also have a potential of $0$.
2. The charges on the conductor redistribute themselves between the conductor and the surface so that every point of the conductor-surface system is at the same potential. If however the surface is connected to ground (which is not clear from your question) then the charges on the conductor will simply all flow to ground leaving the surface and conductor both unchanged.
3. The role of the wire is to allow charges to flow from the conductor to the surface.

Hope this helps.